# Trying to make a simple calculator, JButtons aren't showing up. Why?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I can't get my `Jbuttons` to show up on my `JPanel` or `JFrame`, I'm new to programming still and struggling.

SimpleCalculator:

```
package simplecalculator;

public class SimpleCalculator {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFrame aFrame = new MyFrame();
    aFrame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

MyFrame:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame { 

 public MyFrame(){
   super();

   this.setTitle("Simple Calculator");
   this.setVisible(true);
   MyPanel aPanel = new MyPanel();
   this.getContentPane().add(aPanel);
   aPanel.setVisible(true);
   this.setSize(500, 300);
   }
  }
```

MyPanel:

```
package simplecalculator;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
 int ans=0;

 JTextField result = new JTextField();
 JButton but0 = new JButton("0");
 JButton but1 = new JButton("1");
 JButton but2 = new JButton("2");
 JButton but3 = new JButton("3");
 JButton but4 = new JButton("4");
 JButton but5 = new JButton("5");
 JButton but6 = new JButton("6");
 JButton but7 = new JButton("7");
 JButton but8 = new JButton("8");
 JButton but9 = new JButton("9");


 public MyPanel() {
    super();

    result.setVisible(true);
    result.setLocation(20, 20);
    but0.setText("0");
    but0.setVisible(true);
    but0.setLocation(40, 40);
  }
```

I'm trying to make a simple calculator but I'm stuck. Someone please help.

Comment: where do you add your buttons to your panel?

Comment: Have you actually tried adding your buttons to `MyPanel`?

Comment: Yeah I noticed I never did that, dumb mistakes but that's how a person learns, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your buttons to your panel.

For example:

`JPanel n;
n.add(but0);
n.add(but1);`
etc...

Also try using a Layout with your calculator.
For example:

```
JPanel n = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4));
```

You can also use different layouts to suit your needs. Check this website out for more layouts: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_layouts.htm